# Select, groupby by subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below query works perfect for counting distinct UNIQUE_MEM_ID for any row that had amount>0.  I would like to change the logic of this query to capture distinct UNIQUE_MEM_ID that had sum(amount) > 100 **in a single month**.

Conceptually, changing logic from had amount > 100 in any row, to sum(amount) > 100 for any user in a month.

```
select to_char(optimized_transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month, cobrand_id as cobrand,
   count(distinct UNIQUE_MEM_ID) as distinct_count
into temp_09.z_members
from yi_fourmpanel.card_panel
and amount >0
group by  to_char(optimized_transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'), cobrand;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `having` clause:

```
select to_char(optimized_transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month,
       cobrand_id as cobrand,
       count(distinct UNIQUE_MEM_ID) as distinct_count
into temp_09.z_members
from yi_fourmpanel.card_panel
group by to_char(optimized_transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'), cobrand
having sum(amount) > 100;
```

Comment: I ran this query and it returned the same value as if "having sum(amount) > 100" was not in the query. To be sure, I changed the logic to "having sum(amount) > 10000" where there should be some difference, but no difference. Just so I am clear, I am looking for "having sum(amount) > 100" for each UNIQUE_MEM_ID, not for each cobrand. I believe your query is for the latter

Comment: any thoughts?  Thank you